# Why does an overlay not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, overlay

I have an overlay. If the user clicks on a box the overlay slides up. My problem now is, that the overlay works without any issues in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome. But in Explorer the overlay goes all over the display. How can I solve this problem for IE? Is there something I didnt see? Or do I need a plugin for that?

[image]

This picture shows the normal version which I want to work in IE. 
At the Moment it looks like this in IE.

[image]

```js
    $('.top').on('click', function() {
 $parent_box = $(this).closest('.box');
 $parent_box.siblings().find('.overlay').slideUp();
 $parent_box.find('.overlay').slideToggle(1000, 'swing');
    });


    $('.overlay').on('click', function() {
 $parent_box.find('.overlay').slideToggle(1000, 'swing');
    });
```

```css
    .services-section {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    height: auto;
    }

    .services-section hr {
    border-bottom: hidden;
    width: 42px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .services-section .services-detail {
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 60px 40px 60px 40px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    background-color:rgba(237, 238, 239, 0.8);
    height: 500px;
    }

    .services-section .services-detail:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 0px rgba(90, 91, 95, 0.3);
    top: -2px;
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
    color:#000;
    }

    .services-section .services-detail {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .services-section .services-detail:hover .fa {
    color: #fd2034;
     }

    .services-detail h5 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }

    .services-detail:hover h5 {
    color: #000;
    }

    .services-detail p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    }

    .services-detail:hover p {
    color: #000;
    }

    .overlay{
    display: none; /* Hidden by default*/
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place*/
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 2%;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 92%; /* Full height */
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed 
    background-color: rgb(217,217,217); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
    }

    .overlay h3{
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    }

    .overlay p {
    font-size: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .overlay a {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: black;
    float:left;
    }
    .overlay-header {
    padding: 1px 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffcc00;
    }
    .overlay img{
    width: 18%;
    float: right;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-right: -20%;
    }
    .des{
     margin: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    }

    .overlay:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 0px rgba(90, 91, 95, 0.3);
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
    color:#000;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provider Section Start -->
        <section id="provider" class="services-section section-space-padding 
    mica-bg">
              <div class="container">
     <div class="section-title">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
    <h3 class="white-color"><span>Blume</span></h3>
      </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 3d-hover box">
                 <div class="services-detail hover-effect-2d top">
     <i><img src="container/rfid/micarfid.png" alt="micarfid" 
              style="background-color:#ffcc00; border:5px solid #ffcc00; border-
              radius: 10px; width:200px; margin-left:-15px;"></i>
     <h5>Blume</h5>
     <hr>
     <p>This is a test for blume.</p>
    </div>
                 <div class="overlay">
                     <div class="overlay-header">
                        <img src="test/blume.jpg" alt="blume" style="width:15%;float:right; margin-right:10%;margin-top:0.5%;background:#ffcc00;border:2px solid #ffcc00; border-radius: 10px;">
                         <h3>Blume</h3>
                     </div>
                    <div class="des">
                         <p>This is a test for blume.<</p>
                     </div>  
                     <div class="body col-md-10 col-sm-6">
                         
                         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmufiY2VMjI" target="_blank"><p style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;float:left;">Tutorial</p><i class="fa fa-youtubeOverlay fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="body col-md-10 col-sm-6">
                         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmufiY2VMjI" target="_blank"><p style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;float:left;">PDF-Doku</p><i class="fa fa-pdfOverlay fa-file-pdf-o" style="margin-top:-10px;"></i></a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="body col-md-10 col-sm-6">
                         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmufiY2VMjI" target="_blank"><p style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;float:left;">Image Download</p><i class="fa fa-zipOverlay fa-file-archive-o" style="margin-top:-15px;"></i></a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="body col-md-10 col-sm-6">
                         <a href="test.txt"><p style="width:100%;margin-top:8px;">Application Download</p><i class="fa fa-imgOverlay fa-picture-o" style="margin-top:-80px;"></i></a>
                         
                         <img src="images/application.png" alt="application" style="width:80%;float:left; margin-top:-20px;margin-left:50px;">
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
      <!-- Provider Section End -->


    <!-- Back to Top Start -->
    <a href="#" class="scroll-to-top"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i></a>
    <!-- Back to Top End -->



    <!-- All Javascript Plugins  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugin.js"></script>
      
    <!-- Main Javascript File  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that this issue is caused by the use of `position: fixed` in your overlay element.

Position fixed elements geometry historically relates to the initial containing block (most often the viewport).

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning

For a full cross browser implementation try using `position:absolute` instead, making sure the containing element (div.box) makes use of `position:relative`.

Comment: thank u. I changed my     position: fixed into position: absolute and it does work now in IE as well.